# LINQ TOP rows and exclude TOP rows

Tags: linq

I have to write two LINQ query,which one returns the TOP 6 rows and the another which return data excluding the TOP 6 rows:

```
TOP 6:
from m in MyTable
take 6
select m.Foo
```

I need help how to figure out the second query.

Comment: `Take` and `Skip` in query syntax works only in VB.NET, in C# you need to write method syntax or surround it with parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `MyTable.Skip(6)`.  I don't think there is a way to do this in the query syntax.  Read more about `Take` and `Skip` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Use [Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx) (according to your C# like syntax):

```
var fullList = from m in MyTable select m.Foo;
var top6 = from m in MyTable take 6 select m.Foo;
var top6except = fullList.Except(top6);
```

This exclude the TOP 6 rows retrieved and not generally the top 6 rows. Use `Skip` method to achieve the generic "select starting from 7th row"

Answer (score 0):

To take all but the first 6 rows, use `Skip()`:

```
var allButFirst6 = (from m in MyTable
  select m.Foo).Skip(6);
```

Please note that some LINQ providers require the list to be ordered in order to use `Skip` and `Take`. If this is the case, then use `OrderBy` to order the list before using `Skip` or `Take`.